# elastic search: check for two values (term) in same field (nested) give no result (with one value gives results)

Tags: elasticsearch, match

I've got a problem with ES when i try to check for 2 (or +2) values; that are existing in an nested doc.

First the data i put into ES and afterwards the exact case that did not work.

**Mapping**

```
POST /test
{
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "attributes": {
               "type": "nested"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Testdata**

```
POST /test/doc/1 { "attributes": [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 3}] }
POST /test/doc/2 { "attributes": [{"id": 3}, {"id": 5}] }
POST /test/doc/3 { "attributes": [{"id": 5}] }
```

**Request**

```
POST /test/doc/_search
{
   "query": {
      "nested": {
         "path": "attributes",
         "query": {
            "constant_score": {
               "filter": {
                  "bool": {
                     "must": [
                        {
                           "term": {
                              "attributes.id": 3
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Result that works (only one attribute requested)**

```
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "attributes": [
                  {
                     "id": 3
                  },
                  {
                     "id": 5
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "attributes": [
                  {
                     "id": 1
                  },
                  {
                     "id": 2
                  },
                  {
                     "id": 3
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

now i try to check against 2 attribute ids and i've got an empty result

**Request (2 attributes)**

```
POST /test/doc/_search
{
   "query": {
      "nested": {
         "path": "attributes",
         "query": {
            "constant_score": {
               "filter": {
                  "bool": {
                     "must": [
                        {
                           "term": {
                              "attributes.id": 3
                           }
                        },
                        {
                           "term": {
                              "attributes.id": 5
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Result**

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 0,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": []
   }
}
```

As in the Result in the single request, i've got an  document with attribute ids 3 and 5. Now i've got an empty result.

**EDIT:**

solution for my problem was to not use nested object!

```
POST /test
{
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "attributes": {
               "type": "integer"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}


POST /test/doc/1 
{ "attributes": [1, 2, 3] }
POST /test/doc/2 
{ "attributes": [3, 5] }
POST /test/doc/3
{ "attributes": [5] }

POST /test/doc/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "term": {
                  "attributes": 3
               }
            },
            {
               "term": {
                  "attributes": 5
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a correct behavior of a nested object relationship. Nested mappings tell that nested object is indexed as separate hidden documents and query is made on each nested object, not on the entire collection. You said in your query that find me an attribute where id = 3 and id = 5. To be honest to you scenario is to better take a look at an inner object mapping. This article provides an explanation when inner object and nested object should be used based on a very similar example: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html 
 
Below you can find information how data are stored for an inner object and for a nested object. Many times people using nested mapping for collection but don’t know the consequence of this decision so I think you should rethink your approach.
 Inner object will generate something like that:

```
attributes.id [1,2,3]
attributes.id [3,5]
attributes.id [5]
```

nested will generate something like that:

```
attributes.id [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 3}]
attributes.id [{"id": 3}, {"id": 5}] 
attributes.id [{"id": 5}]
```